# Handheld barcode reader interface

Tags: barcode, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I like to read the barcodes with barcode reader ,am using CODE Barcode reader [Barcode reader](http://www.codecorp.com/products.php?id=138)I like to see the scanned content what exactly the scanner is reading if its is having any extra chars or non printable chars as we have an android app to send scanned content to PC through socket communication.

Comment: So what's your question? Which bit of the process isn't working?

Comment: We are assuming barcode scanner is appending some additional chars to the content which is not visible on text editors as when we scan with scanner data is placing at appropriate place wher as with mobile app data is not placing at proper place in Epic application

Comment: Remove variables from the equation, eg pair it directly with a bluetooth-enabled laptop and write a program to capture characters it sends (last time I played with a barcode scanner, they presented as a Human Interface Device and emulated key presses, but I have no idea if that's how this one works). Start writing the program and if you hit a problem, ask here. You're not going to find someone here to write the program for you, especially since it requires specific hardware to test.

Comment: I want to append preamble and postamble chars to scanned content through mobile app scanned resut before sending to .Net service through socket communication . i have appended like "\\"(preamble)+"125abc"+"\\"(terminator) the result i am getting is \125abc\ in notepad editor and handheld scanner also giving same result but issue is mobile through scanned results are not adding to Epic application like scanner is adding